# Get link_stats for many..MANY urls

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, facebook-fql

I'm looking for a way to get the count of all likes in my website for urls like "product/0", "product/1" ... "product/10000" and currently I'm doing it by sending FQL with a very, very long url (WHERE url IN (....)) and the limit is like ~400 urls to check in one query.

Is there a way to get them with short query, for example "WHERE url LIKE "...product/%" or something, or some other way different than fql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you might be better off monitoring your own traffic and keeping your own stats, such as how many views you get for each url.  If there is a different way to query FB likes, I suspect it is subject to the same 400 URL limit.

Comment: Why ever do you need this, why not just request fresh count in asynchronous manner every time or from time to time at the time page is viewed?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Batch Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) to run more than one query.

I'm not aware if limits you are speaking about related to number of items requested or query/request size so it may or may not help you...